# Python: issue with open file and lines in it

Tags: python, paramiko

I've started this little project of my own, to create a python script that will connect to Linux servers via SSH and will run commands on them. 
This was successful, but when I attempted to use a list of IPs from a file, I ran into the problem where it will only connect to one of the IPs (just one line) in the file. The file contains the following entries :

172.18.8.130

172.18.8.137

And the problem is that the script only returns output from the second IP:

['Linux 172.18.8.137 4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 5 02:00:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux\n']

The code is

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

with open(r'D:\servers.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
     line = (fp.read())

ssh.connect(line, 22, "root", "password")

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("uname -a")

print (stdout.readlines())
```

How can I make it to go through all of the lines (IPs) in that file, so it will connect and run uname -a on all of the servers ?

Comment: You only read a single line and replace the contents of `line` in every iteration. But that's a good thing, because I bet you cannot put multiple lines in that next line either. Re-think the concept of "loop".

Comment: you don't need `line = fp.read()` - you already have line because you use `for line in fp`

Comment: you do for line in fp (which would iterate line by line for you. However in your case the first line is stored in teh variable line. then you overwrite that first line with raeding all the rest of the file. so you lost the first line. Also you prob want your ssh lines indentedin the loop also as you want to ssh for each line. Currently you read the first line throw it away and red the rest of th file. then try to ssh on the last entry only

Comment: you have to run code inside `for`-loop. And don't forget to remove `\n` from the end of line - ie. `line = line.strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that files are IO devices (just like stdout, stdin, etc.) in python. So if you are trying to read each line in a file, you would want to use `fp.readline()` instead of `fp.read()`. `read` reads the entire contents of the file (until EOF is reached) whereas `readline` reads until a new line character is reached.

Try replacing your code with something like this and see if it works for you:

```py
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

with open(r'D:\servers.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for ip in [line.strip() for line in fp.readlines()]:
        ssh.connect(ip, 22, "root", "password")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("uname -a")
        print (stdout.readlines())
```

This reads all lines into a list and strips any extra whitespace characters from the beginning and the end, then we can iterate over this array in our for loop referencing each IP address, opening a connection, and performing whatever tasks you need.

Comment: Your single `for` line reads the entire file in one go to create that list to loop over. While it's likely not going to be a problem in this specific case (), it's still very easily circumvented, and I'd strongly suggest you to use the one line at a time approach instead. It will be useful when handling much (*much*) larger files.

Comment: Yeah the generator looks cleaner but deffinitely know your use case and prepare appropriately. I assumed with the IP addresses in a file it probably wouldnt be an issue to read them all and strip them in one expression. There will probably be more network issues if you have a large file (since they are opening ssh connections to every server), but yeah always keep your use case in mind if you want your solution to scale.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of your for loop, you are updating the "line" variable. Since you have 2 different IP addresses in your list, the "line" variable is always assigned to the second one.

In order to store your IP addresses in your program, use a list.

```
IP_list = []
with open(r'D:\servers.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip() 
        IP_list += [line]
```

Comment: you have to add list `IP_list += [line]` or you get list `["1", "7", "2", ".", "1", "8", ...` instead of `["172.18.8.130"]`

Comment: and don't forget to remove `\n` at the end of line because you will have `"172.18.8.130\n"` and other functions may not accept `\n` in IP